# SQL Server Express 2017 Installation Fails

Tags: installation, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server Express 2017 on a Windows 10 PC, but I keep getting the following error at the very end of the installation:

**The following error has occurred: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.**